# Norm relation with induction

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\rho: H\to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation, where $H$ is a subgroup of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}).$ Let $G$ be another subgroup of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ such that $H$ has finite index in $G$. For any element $A\in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ we define its norm $||A||$ to be maximum modulus of its entries. Denote $\tilde{\rho}=\text{Ind}_{H}^{G}\rho$. I can see that $||\rho(\gamma)||\leq ||\tilde{\rho}(\gamma)||$ for any $\gamma \in H$. However, I want a result something like $ ||\tilde{\rho}(\gamma)|| \ll ||\rho(\gamma)||,$ where the absolute constant depends only on $G$ or $H,$ but not on $\gamma.$

Note that, $$||\tilde{\rho}(\gamma)||=\max_{g_i's~\mathrm{are~coset~representatives~of}~G/H}\{||\rho(g_i\gamma g_j^{-1})||]\}.$$ For such fixed $g_i,g_j$ is it possible to say $||\rho(g_i\gamma g_j^{-1})||\ll ||\rho(\gamma))||$ ?